# How can I achieve project specific indentation in vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, indentation

I'm working on several projects, each of which uses different indentation style (for various filetypes). For example 1 tab per indentation level, 2 or 4 spaces etc. How can I automate switching between these different styles? I normaly prefer indenting with tabs, but I'm tired of having to type :set expandtabs all the time when working with space-indented code. Possible solutions would include loading a piece of vim configuration based on file path or some configuration in the project root. Is there a plugin to solve this for me in an elegant way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Look at the `cinoptions` option and `softtabstop` option (and `expandtab`, but you know that).
2. In your '~/.vimrc', define buffer entry auto-commands for each directory where you keep sources of some project like:

   ```
   augroup ProjectSetup
   au BufRead,BufEnter /path/to/project1/* set et sts=2 cindent cinoptions=...
   au BufRead,BufEnter /path/to/project2/* set noet sts=4 cindent cinoptions=...
   augroup END
   ```

   If the project has mixture of languages and needs different settings for then, you can also
   add extensions like:

   ```
   au BufRead,BufEnter /path/to/project1/*.{c,h} set noet sts=0 cindent cinoptions=...
   au BufRead,BufEnter /path/to/project1/*.py set et sts=4
   ```

Comment: Can you suggest a way to distinguish between languages based on vim filetypes, not file extensions? I like your answer, but this part seems like repeating parts of my configuration. Thanks!

Comment: @VoY: There is also `FileType` event for autocommands. But it's pattern matches the filetype, so you have to check the path yourself. Or you can put code in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<language>.vim`, but you again have to then check the path yourself.

Answer (score 15):

I use the plugin [localvimrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441), which does exactly what you are asking for:

> Sometimes, when you work on different projects, you have the problem, that they use different indentation, tab expansion and so on. You need vimrc for each project that overrides your prefered settings from ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 8):

[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) and it's [Vim plugin](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim#readme):

> What is EditorConfig?
>
> EditorConfig helps developers define and maintain consistent coding
>   styles between different editors and IDEs. The EditorConfig project
>   consists of a file format for defining coding styles and a collection
>   of text editor plugins that enable editors to read the file format and
>   adhere to defined styles. EditorConfig files are easily readable and
>   they work nicely with version control systems.

Among few other things it allows you to set indentation, which will be applied only for this project. It's very simple and most importantly standardized way supported by many different editors and IDE-s, so that it will set the proper indentation not only for you but likely all people working on a project.

You just need to create a `.editorconfig` file in the project root and Vim automatically finds it (assuming you have the plugin installed), setting the proper values. **Creating `.editorconfig` files for each project achieves what you need - project specific indentation.**

Example config file:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.{js,html}]
indent_size = 2

[*.css]
indent_size = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, there is:** If you're using the [Project Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69), you could specify a file whose content is being evaluated every time you open a file of the project (this file is called `in.vim`). The opposite of `in.vim` is `out.vim`: this one's executed every time you leave the project.

Comment: Actually I use project plugin, but switched to the autocommands (see the other answer) for setting up project-specific options (I also set things like makeprg and such). The problem with project plugin's in/out.vim is, that it's not run if you first enter a buffer not from the project plugin but for example from quickfix list (after `:make` or `:grep`) or explicit command (`:e %:r.h` is often quite useful in C/C++).

Answer (score 2):

For everything that Editorconfig supports, the right answer is to use it, see the separate answer for that.

For other settings though, you could use `.vimrc` files with `set exrc secure`.

See `:h exrc`:

```
     d. If the 'exrc' option is on (which is NOT the default), the current
    directory is searched for three files.  The first that exists is used,
    the others are ignored.
    -  The file ".vimrc" (for Unix, Amiga and OS/2) (*)
            "_vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
    -  The file "_vimrc" (for Unix, Amiga and OS/2) (*)
            ".vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
    -  The file ".exrc"  (for Unix, Amiga and OS/2)
            "_exrc"  (for MS-DOS and Win32)
```

See `:h secure`:

```
    When on, ":autocmd", shell and write commands are not allowed in
    ".vimrc" and ".exrc" in the current directory and map commands are
    displayed.  Switch it off only if you know that you will not run into
    problems, or when the 'exrc' option is off.  On Unix this option is
    only used if the ".vimrc" or ".exrc" is not owned by you.  This can be
    dangerous if the systems allows users to do a "chown".  You better set
    'secure' at the end of your ~/.vimrc then.
    This option cannot be set from a |modeline| or in the |sandbox|, for
    security reasons.
```